# Good practice. Structure of folders and files in Angular

Tags: angular

Does anyone know where to find a complete example project, to know the good practices of Angular?.

I would especially like to learn the most appropriate archives and directories structure to develop with Angular.

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO, but note that the Angular team have an example quickstart and a CLI that sets up their recommended structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the official Angular style guide: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Angular CLI to create a new project (`ng new my-app`), it will create the diirectory structure for you. See https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#the-src-folder .